# SQL Server Multiple Running Totals

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table like this

| UserID | Score | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 6 | 2010-1-1 |
| 7 | 8 | 2010-1-2 |
| 5 | 4 | 2010-1-3 |
| 6 | 3 | 2010-1-4 |
| 7 | 4 | 2010-1-5 |
| 6 | 1 | 2010-1-6 |

I would like to get a table like this

| UserID | Score | RunningTotal | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 6 | 6 | 2010-1-1 |
| 5 | 4 | 10 | 2010-1-3 |
| 6 | 3 | 3 | 2010-1-4 |
| 6 | 1 | 4 | 2010-1-6 |
| 7 | 8 | 8 | 2010-1-2 |
| 7 | 4 | 12 | 2010-1-5 |

Thanks!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860966/calculate-a-running-total-in-sqlserver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike `Oracle`, `PostgreSQL` and even `MySQL`, `SQL Server` has no efficient way to calculate running totals.

If you have few scores per `UserID`, you can use this:

```
SELECT  userId,
        (
        SELECT  SUM(score)
        FROM    scores si
        WHERE   si.UserID = so.UserID
                AND si.rn <= so.rn
        )
FROM    (
        SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID) AS rn
        FROM    scores
        ) so
```

, however, this will be very inefficient for larger tables.

For larger tables, you could benefit from using (God help me) a cursor.

Comment: thanks for this. couple of syntax errors but it was enough to set me on my way. the "si.userId = so.UserID" was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you...?

```
SELECT UserID, Score, 
   (SELECT SUM(Score) 
   FROM TableName innerTable 
   WHERE innerTable.UserID = outerTable.userID 
      AND innerTable.Date <= outerTable.date) AS RunningTotal
FROM TableName outerTable
```

This assumes, though, that a user cannot have more than one score per day. (What is your PK?)